# Hack a @Component bean in the context at runtime and override one of its particular field-injected dependencies (no test-scope)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a case where an Spring AutoConfiguration class is getting its dependencies through field injection and creating  and exposing certain beans after interacting with them.

I would like to override one of its dependencies so the exposed beans are initialized in the way I expect.

Obviously I can disable the Autoconfiguration class and duplicate it completely locally with my desired dependency, but that would not be a maintainable solution since the amount of behaviour to reproduce is huge, and it might break on each spring update.

Is there any easy mechanisme to let the autconfiguration be loaded, and later on use the BeanFactory or something to reinject a **particular** instance into a **particular** bean?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee that this is the ideal solution since this is for  topics, instead of classes, but for most cases, it will do the trick.

The `AutoConfiguration` can be disabled in one topic, and any bean in the topic can be initialized using a particular method in the class Configuration (as usual).

[List of `AutoConfiguration`s classes (=topics)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/auto-configuration-classes.html)

[Syntax (to exclude from autoconfiguration):](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
    @bean
    public SpecificClass getSpecificClass() {
        //init the instance as you want
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the point is I am looking for a way to initialize the actual Autoconfiguration, just that Id like to control the injection of one of its dependencies. Redefining the whole logic of the original DataSourceAutconfiguration locally was an approach I already discarded at the end of my question